# filter words for searching in mysql

Tags: mysql, search, select

I want to search in a mysql in 4 format:(for example: the expensive book)

1- all words

2- exact word or phrase

3- any of words

4- none of words

```
SELECT text FROM Items WHERE text LIKE "%'.$searchword.'%";
```

Can somebody help me how can filter words in 'where' section?

Comment: You should probably start by looking into [fulltext indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html) with [boolean mode search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-boolean.html), but note that common words like `'the'` will not usually be indexed because they are on the [stopword list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

Comment: Thanks dear eggyal for your great notes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1) `WHERE text LIKE '%the%' AND text LIKE '%expensive%' AND text LIKE '%book%'`

2) `WHERE text LIKE '%the expensive book%'`

3) `WHERE text LIKE '%the%' OR text LIKE '%expensive%' OR text LIKE '%book%'`

4) `WHERE text NOT LIKE '%the%' AND text NOT LIKE '%expensive%' AND text NOT LIKE '%book%'`

Note that this is not perfectly effective and may take some time on bigger tables, especially 4).

Comment: They'll all perform about as poorly as eachother, since they each require a full table scan.  Also note that patterns like `'%the%'` etc  may match against more than you intend, e.g. `'bother'`: you may wish to use regular expressions with word boundaries instead.